Can OAuth specify the ID and name of the playlist that the app can access when working with the YouTube API?
I'm developing an application that interacts with the YouTube API to access playlists on behalf of users. Is there a way to use OAuth 2.0 to specifically specify the ID and name of the playlist that my app can access, rather than granting broader access to all playlists?
1- OAuth Scope Limitations: I understand that OAuth primarily works based on scopes, where specific permissions are granted to an application. However, I couldn't find a way to directly specify individual playlists or their identifiers during the OAuth authorization process.
-2 Granularity in Access Control: My goal is to achieve a finer level of granularity in accessing playlists, such that users can authorize access to only specific playlists within their account.
-3 Implementation Details: If there's a way to accomplish this through the YouTube API's OAuth flow or by implementing custom logic within my application, I'd appreciate any guidance or examples on how to proceed.
Any insights or suggestions on how to handle playlist-specific authorization using OAuth and the YouTube API would be highly valuable. Thank you!

You are correct in that this is the intent of OAuth scopes, but YouTube (Google) would have to support the particular scope, which they don't at time of writing this.
So, you'd have to implement the logic in your app and have the user supply which playlists she's authorizing access to. But, just as an FYI, the user would be relying on trusting your app to adhere accordingly vs. a third party (Google) restricting access which is the purpose of OAuth.
Here's a link to the page with available scopes (specifically the Data API, but the others are just above and below).
You can see what specific kind of access is required to be authorized in the requests that have requirements like playlist.insert:

Authorization
This request requires authorization with at least one of the following
scopes (read more about authentication and authorization).
Scope
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl

These can be found on the list in the first link.
